# LINQ Query to Find the Maximum Mean for a Time Span

Tags: linq

I have a set of data that has two points; "watts" and a time stamp.

Each data point is separated by 1 second.

So it looks like this:

```
0:01 100
0:02 110
0:03 133
0:04 280
```

.....

The data set is a couple hours long.

I'd like to write a query where I can find the maximum average watts for different time periods (5 seconds, 1 minutes, 5 minutes, 20 minutes, ect).

I'd also like to know where in the data set that maximum average took place.

**Edit**
I think I need to do a query with a moving average and the appropriate bucket (let's say 10 seconds).  Once I get that result, I query that to find the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, a guy at work helped me.  Here's the answer in LINQ Pad.

```
var period = 10;
var rnd = new Random();
// Create some data.
var series = Enumerable.Range(0, 3600)
    .Select(i => Tuple.Create(new TimeSpan(0, 0, i), rnd.Next(300))).ToList();

var item = Enumerable.Range(0, 3600).AsParallel() 
                .Select(i => series.Skip(i).Take(10)) 
                .Select((e, i) => new { Average = e.Sum(x => x.Item2) / e.Count(), Second = i }) 
                .OrderByDescending(a => a.Second).Dump();

                item.First().Dump();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (I used [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/), C# statements):

```
var rnd = new Random();
// Create some data.
var tw = Enumerable.Range(0, 3600)
    .Select(i => Tuple.Create(new TimeSpan(0, 0, i), rnd.Next(1000))).ToList();

// The query.
int secondsPerInterval = 10;
var averages =
tw.GroupBy(t => (int) (t.Item1.TotalSeconds/secondsPerInterval) + 1)
    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        Seconds = g.Key * secondsPerInterval,
                        Avg = g.Average(t => t.Item2)
                    })
    .ToList();

var max = averages.Where(tmp => tmp.Avg == averages.Max(tmp1 => tmp1.Avg)); 
max.Dump();
```

The trick is to group your timespans by the integral part of TotalSeconds divided by the required interval length.

You could do `tw.AsParallel().GroupBy...`, but you should benchmark if you loose more by parallellization overhead than you gain.

Comment: I don't think that pulls in the maximum average.  It also doesn't do a rolling average, it just groups them in buckets of 10.

Comment: I think I need to do a query that calculates the rolling average in 10 second buckets, then a query on top of that to calculate the max from that result.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now. Adapted my answer. The way I suggests allows for "holes" or other irregularities in the timestamps. Your approach will work, but you need knowledge of the data up front. Especially the repetition of the `Enumerable.Range` part is awkward in a real life scenario.

Answer (score 0):

try this (**untested**):

```
for (int i = 0; i < = dataList.count ; i = i + (TimePeriod))
  (from p in dataList.Skip(i).Take(TimePeriod) select p).Average(s => s.Watts)
```

Comment: Sorry i dont know much about PLINQ. hope you get other answers with PLINQ