# Linq Gouping by Arbitrary Timespans

Tags: .net, linq

I have a series of timestamped data points that I wish to group by arbitrary Timepsan values,

So for instance I would like to do something like:

```
var span = Timespan.FromMinutes(5);
var grouped = from dataPoint in data
              group dataPoint by dataPoint.ThisISWhereIGetStuck(span) into argregateData
              select new {
                  Avg = argregateData.Average(x => x.Counter),
                  Span = argregateData.Key.SpanStartTime //or some such
              };
```

Is this possible using linq?

Comment: See the grouping in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998140/linq-query-to-find-the-maximum-mean-for-a-time-span/9000741#9000741

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is assuming I've understood you correctly...)

Well, one simple option is:

```
var span = Timespan.FromMinutes(5);    
var grouped = from dataPoint in data
              group dataPoint by GroupTime(dataPoint.SomeDateTime, span)
                  into aggregateData
              select new {
                  Avg = aggregateData.Average(x => x.Counter),
                  Start = aggregateData.Key
              };


...

private static DateTime GroupTime(DateTime dateTime, TimeSpan span)
{
    long ticks = span.Ticks;
    return new DateTime((dateTime.Ticks / ticks) * ticks);
}
```

That's less efficient than it might be, mind you - a more efficient version would be:

```
var span = Timespan.FromMinutes(5);
long ticks = span.Ticks;
var grouped = from dataPoint in data
              group dataPoint by dataPoint.SomeDateTime.Ticks / ticks
                  into aggregateData
              select new {
                  Avg = aggregateData.Average(x => x.Counter),
                  Start = new DateTime(aggregateData.Key * ticks)
              };
```

You'll get "interesting" results if you group by (say) 3 minutes and 22 seconds... basically this code starts the buckets at `DateTime.MinValue`...

Answer (score 0):

@Jon - I'm not sure the results are strange if you group by an arbitrary interval, isn't it just that some of the buckets aren't filled? If you capture the bucket number too, you can see what I mean:

```
Module Module1
    Class DataPoint
        Property TimeStamp As DateTime
        Property Counter As Integer

        Public Overloads Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("{0} {1}", TimeStamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), Counter)
        End Function

        Public Sub New(timeStamp As DateTime, counter As Integer)
            Me.TimeStamp = timeStamp
            Me.Counter = counter
        End Sub
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim data As New List(Of DataPoint)
        Dim baseTime = DateTime.UtcNow
        Dim rand As New Random

        ' make some random data, possibly with timestamps out of order
        For i = 0 To 29
            data.Add(New DataPoint(baseTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i * 17 + rand.Next(0, 30)), rand.Next(0, 101)))
        Next

        ' show the data for inspection
        For Each d In data
            Console.WriteLine(d.ToString)
        Next

        ' make the buckets smaller than the expected interval between data
        Dim bucketSize = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.1)

        Dim grps = From datum In data
                   Group datum By bnr = (datum.TimeStamp.Ticks - baseTime.Ticks) \ bucketSize.Ticks
                   Into buckets = Group
                   Select Avg = buckets.Average(Function(x) x.Counter),
                    BucketStart = buckets.First,
                    BucketNumber = bnr,
                    Count = buckets.Count

        Console.WriteLine(grps.Count.ToString & " buckets.")

        ' show that not all buckets are filled/created
        For Each b In grps
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,3} {1,3} {2} {3}", b.BucketNumber, b.Count, b.BucketStart.TimeStamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), Math.Round(b.Avg, 2)))
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```